# How to take derivative of boundary conditions of non linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, differential

I have a nonlinear boundary value problem to solve.

Boundary conditions are given as

r(x(t0),x(tf))=0

and I need to take the derivative of r with respect to x(to) and x(tf) respectively.

I am really confused about how to interpret r(x(t0),x(tf))  to go further with derivatives.

Any help would be appreciated .

Thanks

Comment: Are you just differentiating $r$ or are you trying to differentiate the solution itself with respect to $x(t_0)$ and $x(t_f)$? For differentiating $r$, just think of $x(t_0)$ as one variable, say $y$, and $x(t_f)$ as another, say $z$. The only tricky thing is keeping track of the fact that both $r$ and the solution depend on $y$ and $z$.

Comment: Thanks for comment! I would like to differentiate r with respect to x's in the beginning and end of the time interval, but i  do not understand exactly what r is here.

Comment: If you weren't told what $r$ is then it is just some general function.